# Generate ExampleSet with zeros in RapidMiner

Tags: rapidminer

What is the easiest/correct way to generate an ExampleSet in RapidMiner that looks like this:

[image]

The way I am using now:

[image]

Select Attributes was necessary because ‘Generate Data’ gave me a ‘label’ attribute which I don’t want

Answer (score 0):

Three operators seems to be the minimum. You could use `Generate Data by User Specification` combined with `Loop` and `Append`.  Here's an example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="7.5.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="concurrency:loop" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Loop" width="90" x="246" y="136">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification" width="90" x="179" y="238">
            <list key="attribute_values">
              <parameter key="attribute1" value="0"/>
              <parameter key="anotherattribute" value="0"/>
            </list>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification" from_port="output" to_port="output 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Append" width="90" x="447" y="136"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop" from_port="output 1" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Andrew